# Can't specify rpcport for testnet

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, network, testnet

Was there a recent change where it is no longer possible to specify rpcport?

I noticed these two warnings:
Warning: Config setting for -addnode only applied on test network when in [test] section.
Warning: Config setting for -rpcport only applied on test network when in [test] section.

After trying adding a [test] section I got very mixed results as some times it disregarded all options and in general rpcport was still not set.

I could not find any documentation on how to do this.

Comment: What software are you running exactly?

Comment: I am building the bitcoin daemon from source.

Comment: Can you post your bitcoin.conf file? Also, please read https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes-pr12823.md

Answer (score 5):

For any of `addnode`, `connect`, `port`, `bind`, `rpcport`, `rpcbind`, and `wallet` you should move them into the `[test]` and/or `[main]` sections of your `bitcoin.conf`. You can also move any other setting that you want only applied to mainnet or testnet into the appropriate section.

Example:

```
server=1
daemon=1

[main]
prune=1000

[test]
rpcport=55555
```