# When I specify wallet in bitcoin.conf for testnet3, it gets ignored

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat, bitcoin.conf

I have a question about specifying wallet for testnet3. My bitcoin.conf file is located in the root of the Bitcoin folder with the line `'wallet = receiving.dat` as well as `testnet=1`. Whenever I run 'getwalletinfo' tho it still shows no name for the walletname and if I delete the default wallet.dat, it autoregenerates. This is on version 0.18.0.

Comment: Update: So it appears it's selecting the wallet in the non-test version according to the bitcoin.conf. Now it seems to be how to specify wallet in testnet.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered by [Can't specify rpcport for testnet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/77607/cant-specify-rpcport-for-testnet) but it comes from an issue in the 0.17.XX change where options need to be specified by network type.

Comment: more details [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/11862)